Return root empty array from Jolt instead of null
I have the following input:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "TYPE": "A"
    }
  ]
}

And the following Jolt transform:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "ID": "[&1].id",
          "TYPE": "[&1].type"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

It works fine, and returns:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "A"
  }
]

However when provided:
{     
  "data": [] 
}

It returns null but I want it to return an empty array, like so:
[]

Is there any way to achieve this?

If it would suffice to get
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "TYPE": "A"
  }
]

then the following single spec would handle your problem :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": ""
    }
  }
]

but for your case you can convert it to the following :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "id": "=(@(1,ID))",
          "type": "=(@(1,TYPE))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "ID|TYPE": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": ""
    }
  }
]

third operation of which is the identical with the previously suggested one.
